# Let $d_P$ be the Prokhorov metric on $\mathcal P(X)$. Then $(X, d)$ is compact if and only if $(\mathcal P(X), d_P)$ is compact

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces

In proving the reverse direction of Prokhorov theorem, I have to prove this auxiliary result. Could you verify if my attempt is fine?

---

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $\mathcal{P} :=\mathcal{P}(X)$ the set all Borel probability measures on $X$. Let $d_P$ be the [Prokhorov metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4434016/can-prokhorov-metric-be-extended-to-all-non-negative-finite-borel-measures) on $\mathcal{P}$.

> *Theorem:* $(X, d)$ is compact if and only if $(\mathcal P, d_P)$ is compact.

I post my proof separately as below answer. This allows me to subsequently remove this question from unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $x \mapsto \delta_{x}$ is a homeomorphism from $X$ onto $\left\{\delta_{x} \mid x \in X\right\}$ which is closed in $\mathcal{P}$. If $\mathcal{P}$ is compact, then so is $\left\{\delta_{x} \mid x \in X\right\}$ and thus is $X$. Let's prove the other direction.

Let $E:= \mathcal C_b(X)$. Then $(E, \| \cdot\|_\infty)$ is a Banach space. Let $E'$ be its dual and
$$
\begin{align}
F := &\{\varphi \in E' \mid \|\varphi\| = 1, \varphi \text{ positive}\} \\
= &\{\varphi \in E' \mid \|\varphi\| \le 1, \varphi \text{ positive}, \varphi(1) = 1\}.
\end{align}
$$

Then $F$ is closed in weak* topology of $E'$ and is a subset of the unit ball. By [Banach-Alaoglu theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4369946/a-proof-of-banach-alaoglu-theorem-with-net-convergence), $F$ is compact in weak* topology. Because $X$ is compact, $E$ coincides with the space $\mathcal C_0 (X)$ of functions vanishing at infinity. By [Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4500358/3-versions-of-riesz-markov-kakutani-theorem), the map
$$
T: \mathcal P \to F, \mu \mapsto \left ( \varphi_\mu: f \mapsto \int_X f \mathrm d \mu \right ).
$$
is a bijection.

- Let $\mu, \mu_1,\mu_2, \ldots \in \mathcal P$ such that $\mu_n \to \mu$ in $d_P$. Then $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly, so $\varphi_{\mu_n} \to \varphi_\mu$ in weak* topology. This implies $T(\mu_n) \to T(\mu)$ in weak* topology.
- Let $\varphi_\mu, \varphi_{\mu_1}, \varphi_{\mu_2}, \ldots \in \mathcal P$ such that $\varphi_{\mu_n} \to \varphi_\mu$ in weak* topology. Then $\varphi_{\mu_n} (f) \to \varphi_\mu (f)$ for all $f\in E$, so ${\mu_n} \to \mu$ weakly. Notice that compact metric space is separable. In separable metric space, weak convergence is [equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4434050/if-the-underlying-metric-space-is-separable-then-weak-convergence-is-equivalent) to convergence in $d_P$. This implies $\mu_n \to \mu$ in $d_P$.

As such, $T$ is a sequential homeomorphism. This completes the proof.

Comment: Looks fine to me (at least, this is the standard proof I was once taught).