# Carleman's theorem on a compact interval

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, moment-problem

Let $\mu_n$ be Borel probability measures on $[0, 1]$. I'm trying to prove a special case of [Carleman's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman%27s_condition?useskin=vector), i.e.,

> **Theorem** If the sequence $(\int_0^1 x^k \mathrm d \mu_n (x), n\in \mathbb N)$ converges for all $k \in \mathbb N$. Then there is a Borel probability measures on $[0, 1]$ such that $\mu_n \to \mu$ [weakly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures?useskin=vector#Weak_convergence_of_measures).

Could you confirm if my below attempt is fine? Suggestion for simpler proof is very welcome.

---

**Proof** Let $\mathcal P([0, 1])$ be the space of Borel probability measures on $[0, 1])$. Because $[0, 1]$ is compact, $\mathcal P([0, 1])$ [is compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4436531/let-d-p-be-the-prokhorov-metric-on-mathcal-px-then-x-d-is-compact-i) in topology of weak convergence. So there is a sub-sequence $(n_k)$ and $\mu \in \mathcal P([0, 1])$ such that $\mu_{n_k}  \underset{k \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} \mu$ weakly. It suffices to prove that $(\mu_n)$ converges weakly to $\mu$.

Fix a continuous bounded function $f:[0, 1] \to \mathbb R$. It suffices to prove $\int_0^1 f \mathrm d \mu_n \to \int_0^1 f \mathrm d \mu$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. By  [Weierstrass approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem?useskin=vector#Weierstrass_approximation_theorem), there is a polynomial function $g$ such that $\sup_{x \in [0, 1]} |f(x)-g(x)| < \varepsilon$. So it suffices to prove that $\int_0^1 g \mathrm d \mu_n \to \int_0^1 g \mathrm d \mu$.

Because $\mu_{n_k}  \underset{k \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} \mu$ weakly, we have
$$
\int_0^1 g \mathrm d \mu_{n_k} \underset{k \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} \int_0^1 g \mathrm d \mu.
$$

WLOG, we assume $g (x) = \sum_{i=0}^p a_i x^i$ for some $a_0, \ldots, a_p \in \mathbb R$. Then
$$
\int_0^1 g \mathrm d \mu_n = \sum_{i=0}^p a_i \int_0^1 x^i \mathrm d \mu_n (x).
$$

Because $(\int_0^1 x^i \mathrm d \mu_n (x), n\in \mathbb N)$ converges for all $i=0, \ldots, p$, we get $(\int_0^1  g \mathrm d \mu_n, n\in \mathbb N)$ converges and thus
$$
\lim_n \int_0^1  g \mathrm d \mu_n = \lim_k \int_0^1  g \mathrm d \mu_{n_k} = \int_0^1 g \mathrm d \mu.
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: Yes, your proof is fine.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you so much for your verification! Do you have any idea for a simpler approach?

Comment: No,I don't think  your proof can be simplified.